# Java in Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

Is it any possibility to handle files (on client station) using Java.IO?
I need to access files from user stations not from server.

I have found some codes like as following, but nothing deletes or creates.

Can you help me with this issue?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "JDelete" AS
import java.io.File;
public class JDelete {
  public static int delete (String fileName) {
    File myFile = new File (fileName);
    boolean retval = myFile.delete();
    if (retval) return 1; else return 0;
  }
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    System.out.println (delete (args[0]) );
  }
}

create or replace function fDelete (file IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER 
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'JDelete.delete (java.lang.String) return int';
```

calling from sql

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(fDelete('C:\Rapoarte\u1.txt'));
end;
```

Comment: It is more likely related to filesystem user rights, if it were a code problem you'd get actual execution errors. What does the call output? Probably 0.

Comment: Yes it returns 0 the output.

Comment: So the file is not allowed to be deleted by whatever user is being used, you need to look into the filesystem rights. Not a programming problem.

Comment: Can you tell me what rights and which should have access to the file?

Comment: No is it not possible. Oracle client does not support file manipulation. Java stored code runs on the servers side and sees only files on db server.

Comment: I have found this tutorial. It seems that the files can be manipulated from db https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/file-handling-from-plsql

Comment: "Can you tell me what rights and which should have access to the file?" - no of course not, I don't manage your server :/

Comment: if the files are not on the Oracle server is it possible to manipulate it? (I mean I do not want to use the oracle directory)

Comment: @coco - no. When run from the Oracle database neither Java or PL/SQL can access files which are not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it, but in case it's absolutely necessary you could define a network drive on the server, pointing to a directory on the client disk.. Then use the function to operate on that remote drive.

Consider that this solution will only be valid for one particular client machine.